# Loop in Blogspot

Tags: blogger

I created a blog, used customize theme and I'm editing it, but I dont know much about it. Bros, please help me how I could show post title and image and loop three newest post in it.

```
<div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
                      <div class='item active'>
                        <img alt='data:post.title' title='data:post.title' src='data:post.Image'/>
                        <div class='carousel-caption'>
                          <h2>
                            <data:post.title/>
                          </h2>
                          <p>data:post.content</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to your theme and find string `<b:includable id='main' var='top'>`.

2) After it find section `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>...</b:loop>` - this is what you need.

3) Make your own loop section above this one with needed content.

More info on [Blogger Help](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995) and [OverAPI](http://overapi.com/blogger).